# How can I generate an array of 100 float numbers starting from 0 to 4095 without duplicates in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Is there a one-line function to do this?

```
#define amp 1
#define off 1.5
#define N 100
short int LUT[N];

void rampGen(){
  float Vramp;
  for(int i=0 ; i<N; i++){
    Vramp = (amp*i + off)/N;
    LUT[i] = (short int)(Vramp*(4095.0/3.0));
  }
}
```

The result starts from 20 and finish to 1371 but I need it to start from 0 and end to 4095.

Comment: change the offset to 0 and remove the /3.0 ?

Comment: Actually I need the Vramp to start from 0.0 and end to 3.0. The last conversion is made to convert all the generated values to a range of codes for a DAC

Comment: @MaximeChéramy anyway your solution doesn't work

Comment: Generate 100 distinct values equally spaced between `0` and `4095.0`.    If you need them in some randomised order, shuffle them  (plenty of algorithms available for shuffling).

Answer (score 1):

I've changed a few things in your code:

```
#define amp 3
#define off 0
#define N 100
short int LUT[N];

void rampGen(){
  float Vramp;
  for(int i=0 ; i<N; i++){
    Vramp = (float)(amp * i)/(N - 1) + off;
    LUT[i] = (short int)(Vramp*(4095.0 / amp));
  }
}
```

- "I need the Vramp to start from 0.0 and end to 3.0." then I guess amp should be equal to 3 and off to 0. I've updated the constants accordingly.
- I've added a cast to float in the computation of Vramp